# Making top div be transparent to the page, while a div under it is not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Basically, what I am trying to achieve is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDtHL.gif

As you can see, the popup has 2 kidney shapes, which get peeled off to show the content, but initially they are transparent to the background of the website (articles, etc).

I did not find a way to do it in CSS, (if the top layer of the kidneys is transparent, but the bottom one isn't, it is not going to work).

My idea is to get it done through with dynamically creating a background image, and rendering the page unscrollable once the popup appears, in order to do the peeling effect.

Is there something I am missing, which can help me achieve this easier?
Thank you for your tips

Comment: Just position the `divs` where you want them, give them `opacity: 0; display: none` and when you want them to appear, change the values to `opacity: 1; display: block`

Comment: That doesn't allow to achieve the peel animation effect. Since it will be peeling of a layer (such as on this link http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwNgGY ), there will be 2 absolute divs. The one under is supposed to have the content, but if it has content, it is supposed to be hidden, but the top layer is supposed to be peeled off of the bottom layer, while being transparent to the page background.

Comment: Ohhh okay I understand your situation better now

Answer (score 1):

```
element {
background-color:rgba(110, 110,110,.5);
}

/*the "a"means opacity and the number is from 0~1,also you can make img have opacity.*/


element {
background-color:rgb(110, 110,110,.5);
opacity:0.5;
}
```

the opacity attribute is from 0~1,also you can make img have opacity.or you can make css animation keyframes.the link is here 
[click here to check @keyframe](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp)

Hope the answer able to help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't help at all. But thanks for trying!

Answer (score 1):

Give the child div an absolute position, and control it's position using top, right, left and up css attributes.

```
Position:absolute;
Top:300px;
Left: 50%;
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is an obvious step in any possible solution, related to the actual problem. Unfortunately, doesn't help.

Comment: Well, then I maybe hadn't get your issue, anyway, I suggest inserting your elements or removing them using java script instead of showing and hiding them using css, hope this would help.